# Get deducted results over date range

Tags: c#

I am keeping records of data usage daily and want to display out the total data usage between a date range.

The data resets at 10th every month so an example data usage would be like:

```
Number: 001xxxxxxxx 
Date - Data
8th - 100mb
9th - 120mb
10th - 10mb
11th - 40mb
```

So to get the total data usage between 8th and 11th, it's not possible to take the data at 11th deducted by 8th (40mb-100mb) as it resets at 10th.

I would need something like, 40mb+(120mb-100mb) = 60mb total usage

here is my method that gives the data, date and number into Dictionarys

```
private void getNumberDatas(List<int> phoneNo, DateTime dateStart, DateTime dateEnd)
{
    Dictionary<int, Dictionary<DateTime, float>> d_PhoneNo_DateDataList = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<DateTime, float>>();
    Dictionary<DateTime, float> d_DateTime_Data = new Dictionary<DateTime, float>();

    string strConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["xxx"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString);

    string sqlcommand = "SELECT xxx FROM xxx WHERE PhoneNo=@PhoneNo AND date BETWEEN @Date1 AND @Date2";

    for (int i = 0; i < phoneNo.Count; i++)
    {
        d_DateTime_Data.Clear();

        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlcommand, conn))
        {
            conn.Open();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PhoneNo", phoneNo[i]);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date1", dateStart);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date2", dateEnd);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                d_DateTime_Data.Add(DateTime.Parse(reader["Date"].ToString()), float.Parse(reader["Data"].ToString()));
            }
            conn.Close();
        }
        d_PhoneNo_DateDataList.Add(phoneNo[i], d_DateTime_Data);
    }
}
```

So to get a data for today would be:

```
Dictionary<DateTime, float> temp_Datetime_data = new Dictionary<DateTime, float>();

if (d_PhoneNo_DateDataList.TryGetValue("001xxxxxxxx", out temp_Datetime_data))
{
    float dataToday;

    if (temp_Datetime_data.TryGetValue(DateTime.Today, out dataToday))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(dataToday.ToString());
    }
}
```

Now my problem is that I do not know how to implement the calculations if let's say the user chooses 20th May 2016 to 30th June 2016

Let me know if it's too confusing, I don't know the best way to explain this

Comment: Not sure I'm following. Why can't you just SUM() the data usage values of those dates?

Comment: @silkfire because the data is already a sum and not a daily value

Comment: @silkfire yes, each result is a cumulative of the previous date's data, and only resets at the 10th of each month

Comment: @BloopieBloops Ah thank you, then I understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not perfect but it will be a good base for your needs:

```
private static int getData(Dictionary<DateTime, int> values, DateTime start, DateTime stop)
{
    // Reduce the scope
    var val = values.Where(x => x.Key >= start && x.Key <= stop);

    // Create a list of ranges
    List<Dictionary<DateTime, int>> listOfMonth = new List<Dictionary<DateTime, int>>
    {
        new Dictionary<DateTime, int>()
    };
    var currentMonth = listOfMonth.Last();
    int previousValue = int.MinValue;
    foreach (KeyValuePair<DateTime, int> keyValuePair in val)
    {
        // Reset the month
        if (keyValuePair.Value < previousValue)
        {
            currentMonth = new Dictionary<DateTime, int>()
            {
                {DateTime.Now, 0} // Add placeholder
            };
            listOfMonth.Add(currentMonth);
        }
        previousValue = keyValuePair.Value;

        currentMonth.Add(keyValuePair.Key, keyValuePair.Value);
    }

    return listOfMonth.Sum(dictionary => dictionary.Values.Max() - dictionary.Values.Min());
}
```

With this data:

```
Dictionary<DateTime, int> dataDictionary = new Dictionary<DateTime, int>()
{
    {new DateTime(2016, 8, 4), 20},
    {new DateTime(2016, 8, 5), 50}, 
    {new DateTime(2016, 8, 6), 70}, 
    {new DateTime(2016, 8, 7), 90},
    {new DateTime(2016, 8, 8), 100},
    {new DateTime(2016, 8, 9), 120}, 
    {new DateTime(2016, 8, 10), 10}, 
    {new DateTime(2016, 8, 11), 40}, 
};

DateTime start = new DateTime(2016, 8, 7);
DateTime stop = new DateTime(2016, 8, 11);
```

I get `70` (<kbd>120</kbd>-<kbd>90</kbd>) + (<kbd>40</kbd> - <kbd>0</kbd>)

Comment: @BloopieBloops the main advantage of my solution is that it'll allow you to process range from 1 day to virtually any value. Just be aware that the date have to be sorted, or just add a call to `Sort()`

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, the the problem can be restated as

1. Calculate the sum of the differences between the usages, except
2. On the reset date, use the amount rather than the difference

For example purposes we can use a small usage class

```
class Usage
{
    public Usage(int day, int totalUsage)
    {
        Day = day;
        TotalUsage = totalUsage;
    }
    public int Day { get; }
    public int TotalUsage { get; }
}
```

and a list of usages to represent the log

```
private readonly static List<Usage> Log = new List<Usage>
{
    new Usage(8,100),
    new Usage(9,120),
    new Usage(10,10),
    new Usage(11,40),
};
```

We can calculate the total usage for the periods as follows

```
private void CalcTotalUsage(int startDate, int endDate, int expectedTotal)
{
    // I just used ints for the days for demo purposes, dates will not change the calculation below  
    var records = Log.Where(u => u.Day >= startDate && u.Day <= endDate);

    var total = records.Skip(1).Zip(records, (curr, prev) => (curr.TotalUsage > prev.TotalUsage) ? curr.TotalUsage - prev.TotalUsage : curr.TotalUsage).Sum();

    Assert.AreEqual(expectedTotal, total);

}
```

and the tests to check that it works correctly

```
[TestMethod]
public void CheckTotals()
{
    CalcTotalUsage(8, 9, 20);
    CalcTotalUsage(8, 10, 30);
    CalcTotalUsage(8, 11, 60);
}
```

Comment: sorry, i'm not familiar with the syntax of the var total = records line, could you explain it a little to me? thanks

Comment: It uses `Enumerable.Zip()` to process two copies of the records list. The first one, we start at the 2nd element - using Skip(1) - (this will be our current) and the second we start at the first element (this will be our previous). We then subtract the previous from the current, except where the previous > current (at the reset), where we take the current value. We then sum these to give the aggregate usage. Does this make sense or would an edit to the answer be useful?